# Integration with a change of basis turns the result negative

Tags: integration, change-of-basis, change-of-variable

I am calculating the average kinetic energy of a simple harmonic oscillator via

$$\frac{1}{2A}\int_{-A}^A \frac{m}{2}\dot{x}^2dx = \frac{m}{4A}\int_{\text{half period}}\dot{x}^2
\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) dt= \frac{m}{4A}\int_{\text{half period}}\dot{x}^3 dt$$

However, now when I carry the integration through, I get a negative value instead of the expected positive quantity. Otherwise, the value appears to be correct. Can anyone offer insight as to what I missed? Was the quantity $\frac{dx}{dt}$ supposed to be $\|{\frac{dx}{dt}}\|$?

Comment: There are a few different explanations for it, but one is Jacobians must always be positive so we take the absolute value and automatically order the bounds from low to high. Another explanation, with parametric equations such as this, you always need to be conscious to choose the order that matches the same correct start and end points.

Comment: You were right. My bounds were wrong. Thanks!